# JavaScript: Overhead comparison between closure and a global function

Tags: javascript, performance, closures

I want to know the overhead of JavaScript closures. Suppose I have the following function:

```
function sum(arr, sumMethod) {
  var totalSize = 0;
  for (index = 0; index < arr.length; ++index) {
    totalSize += sumMethod(arr[index]);
  }
  return totalSize;
}
```

If I want to know the total size of all my transfers, then I could use a global accessor function to obtain the size of a transfer. This function is passed to `sum`:

```
// Use a "global" method that is initialize only once
function getTransferSize(transfer) { return transfer.size };

...

// Obtain the total size of all transfers (called pretty often)
var totalTransferSize = sum(transfers, getTransferSize);
```

Another approach is to inline the accessor like this:

```
// Obtain the total size of all transfers (called pretty often)
var totalTransferSize = sum(transfers, function (transfer) { return transfer.size });
```

I would think the closure is only "compiled" once and reused over and over again, so the actual execution performance would be equal. A collegue of mine thinks that the closure is created over and over again and it hurts performance.

Can anyone explain what is the preferred method?

**REMARK:** I am actually using CoffeeScript, which makes closures much more readable. In CoffeeScript the code would look like this:

```
totalTransferSize = sum transfers, (t) -> t.size
```

I find this much more readable then using a global accessor function, so I would prefer to inline the accessor.

Comment: The code is compiled only once, but the function expression will create multiple function objects.

Comment: So the garbage collection would be a bit more busy. But the other one holds on to the memory until the end-of-times. Not that it would be a lot of memory...

Comment: Yes. It's just about creating a global variable to hold a value, or creating the value every time needed from a literal expression. Hardly measurable if at all - the compiler even might optimize the one case into the other.

Answer (score 2):

A collegue of mine thinks that the closure is created over and over again

Yes. Every time the function expression is evaluated, a new function object is instantiated.

> and it hurts performance.

Unlikely. If you'd really care, measure it. The instantiation is probably much cheaper than the loop with the calls.

> I would think the closure is only "compiled" once and reused over and over again

Yes, the code is compiled only once and shared by all the function instances.

> so the actual execution performance would be equal.

Of the single call, yes.